# SVN Log After Loading Dump Into New Repository

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I have transferred my SVN repository from one server to another.  I used the `dump` command to backup the original repository:

```
svnadmin dump repo-one > /tmp/repo-one.svn.dump
```

The on my new server, I loaded the dump file into a new repository of the same name:

```
svnadmin load /home/svnadmin/svn/repo-one < /home/svnadmin/svn/repo-one.svn.dump
```

I can see that the dump was loaded successfully, and the 350-odd revisions have all imported successfully.

When I use the "TortoiseSVN Repo-browser" to view the files, I can connect and view the latest files.  On the old server when I click on the 'HEAD' button amd then click on the `Show log` button this brings up a list of all the changes.

On the new server I get an error message:

```
There has been a problem contactng the server.
Do you want to see the cached data instead?
```

Any ideas what is causing the log to not show the history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong area - I assumed that "TortoiseSVN"  was in error here, but in fact it was a setting in the new repository.

My new repository is located:

```
/home/svnadmin/svn/repo-one
```

When this repository (and any repository) is created, there is a `svnserve.conf` file also created which is located:

```
../repo-one/conf/svnserve.conf
```

Using your favourite text editor open the `svnserve.conf` file and locate the line that reads:

```
anon-access = read
```

Replace the `read` value with `none` so that the line now looks like this:

```
anon-access = none
```

Save the file, and attempt to access the log using "TortoiseSVN" and the full log will then be available again.